# Ubuntu 16.10 Display Port monitors Not Recognized

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, fglrx, amd-graphics, displayport

Context, my system is HP 745 G4 (AMD APU A12-9800B) with a display port output which is split to 3 monitors and a main laptop monitor. This setup is working under windows. The main laptop monitor is recognized as a separate output in all Linux installations thus far.

I originally installed Ubuntu 16.10 that I had on put on a usb stick at an unknown time. This worked, I was able to select each monitor individually and choose extended setup etc.

Flash forward 3 months to installing Ubuntu 16.10 on a new SSD (I don't have the old install) and the three monitors are only recognized as "Ancor 24"" and are all duplicated. I am unable to recognize individual monitors.

I'm not sure what would cause this, I have upgraded to 17.04 with no change. On the first install it worked upon the first boot, this time around I have run updates and restarted to no success. There are no Linux drivers on AMD's page for my processor, and I don't want to revert to 16.04 with Fglrx. My APU is not supported by AMDGPU Pro.